# Switch between 2 global SCSS using selector

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, sass, ng-upgrade

I'm upgrading my company AngularJS project to Angular 8 thanks to ngUpgrade. So I have a hybrid application with both angularjs and angular components. I am also using an angular material template that provides SCSS files for both angular and angularjs.

My problem is that I want to only use the ajs theme on ajs component and the angular theme on angular components (and they can also be nested).

I searched a way to apply only one global css when a specific class is applied and switch to another global css when another class is applied.
I cant really do css lazy loading in this case

Lets assume my app code looks like this :

```html
<div class="theme-1">
    <div>Some stuff that should get theme 1 CSS</div>
    <div class="theme-2">
        <div>Some stuff that need ONLY theme 2 CSS</div>
        <div>without theme 1 CSS</div>
        <div class="theme-1">
            <div>Switching back to theme 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to switch between theme when a class `theme-1` or `theme-2` occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to use `encapsulation: shadowDow` on my angular components. It allowed me to reset theme1 css and use only theme2 css.

I had t do lots of css tweaks (some angular material features doesn't work with shadowDom...) and an cant switch back to theme1, but it has been the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

you should use BEM approach for this and your code should be like this.

```
.theme-1 {
    &__div1{...}
    &__div2{...}
    ...
}

.theme-2 {
    &__div2{...}
    ...
}
.theme-1,
.theme-2 {
    /* Common Css */
    &__div1{...}
    &__div2{...}
    ...
}
```

so you can write classes like this now

```
<div class="theme-1__div1">
    <div>Some stuff that should get theme 1 CSS</div>
    <div class="theme-2__div1">
        <div>Some stuff that need ONLY theme 2 CSS</div>
        <div>without theme 1 CSS</div>
        <div class="theme-1__div2">
            <div>Switching back to theme 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for BEM you can refer this link - http://getbem.com/naming/.
If you are still not clear, I can provide same code also.
Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure it's the solution i'm looking for. What I want is to apply the same css for `theme-1__div1` and `theme-1__div2`, so it looks like this will make me duplicate a lot of code. Btw i'm working with this template : http://fusetheme.com/admin-templates/angular/. I dont really get who this solution will disable theme1 css in the theme2 class

Comment: I have updated code for common css, please check once.